# Understanding module.export to pass a parameter

Tags: node.js, module.exports

I have been trying to understand, module.export how to pass a parameter with it. Now I have made a demo server for testing it.

File - index.js

```
var express = require('express');
var check = require('./file');
var app = express();

app.get('/',check.fun1("calling"),(req,res)=>{
    res.send('here i am');
})

app.listen(3000,()=>{
    console.log("Server is up");
})
```

With a middleware check,

```
module.exports = fun1 = name => {
    return function(req, res, next) {
      console.log(name + " from fun1");
      next();
    };
  };

  module.exports = fun2 = name2 => {
    return function(req, res, next) {
      console.log(name + " from fun1");
      next();
    };
  };
```

Now this is not working, but when I change it in, its start to work

```
fun1 = name => {
  return function(req, res, next) {
    console.log(name + " from fun1");
    next();
  };
};

fun2 = name2 => {
  return function(req, res, next) {
    console.log(name + " from fun1");
    next();
  };
};

module.exports = {
  fun1,
  fun2
};
```

Now, this might look like a stupid question, that if it's working then why I am asking but, what change should I make, in index.js file so that my first type of module.export starts working. It's just all out of sheer curiosity

Thanks

Comment: What do you expect `module.exports = fun1 = name => {...}` to do? What's the purpose of `fun1` here? If you want to export two functions from your module, then you write `exports.fun1 = name => {...}` and `exports.fun2 = name2 => {...}`. You only overwrite `module.exports` if you want to export a single value. Not sure how the title of the questions relates to your issue.

Comment: Ok, I get now, exports.mdoule is basically an obj in the module, if I export it twice it gets overwritten, hmmm, making sense. But `exports` is directly converted to module.export hmmm.. thankx

Comment: `exports` is simply a variable in scope of a module and initially references the same value as `module.exports`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A lot of things in node.js are simply design patterns. Node.js introduced exactly zero extensions to javascript when it was originally published (and this includes its module system). Even today, node.js has zero syntax extensions. Node.js is just javascript with additional libraries and a special runtime environment (where all modules are evaluated inside an IIFE)

Having said that, `module.exports` is not syntax. It is simply an ordinary variable in javascript. Specifically, the variable `module` is an object and node's module system will check this `module` variable to see if it has a property named `exports`. If `module` has an `exports` property then its value is taken to be the exported module.

Since `module` is just an ordinary variable it follows normal variable behaviour. If you reassign a variable its value will change. For example:

```
var x = 0;
console.log(x); // prints 0;
x = 100;
console.log(x); // prints 100, not 0 and 100
```

Therefore, the same is true for `module.exports`:

```
module.exports = 'hello';
console.log(module.exports); // prints 'hello'
module.exports = 'world';
console.log(module.exports); // prints 'world', not 'hello world'
```